# Input missing, output on Input line in sublimerepl python

Tags: python, sublimetext2, sublimerepl

Basically, after getting Sublime text 2 and sumblimeREPL up and running, I am having issues when I send code. For instance, in the below screenshot, I enter the code on the left line by line (ctrl+,l), or by block/selection but nothing shows up except the output. In[3]-In[6] I was attempting to run the x and y lines only. Is this the intended behavior? I would have assumed yes, except that all the output is being displayed on the input lines. The only other language I have tried so far is R, and it does not have this issues. Also it is the same issue in both python and ipython. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I'd strongly suggest upgrading to IPython 1.1.0, as while the issue likely isn't related to the older version, it's [well worth](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-1.0.0/whatsnew/version1.0.html) the upgrade, especially if you use it a lot.

If you open `Preferences -> Package Settings -> SublimeREPL -> Settings - Default`, you'll notice that the last line is `"show_transferred_text": false`. I'm on OS X, but when I have this set to `false`, I see the same behavior you do - the result of the expression printed on an `In [#]` line, with another blank line following it, ready for the next expression. However, if I set this variable to `true` (by copying the entire contents of the file, opening `Preferences -> Package Settings -> SublimeREPL -> Settings - User`, pasting everything in there, then changing settings and saving), then I see different behavior when transferring a line: The expression is printed on the `In [#]` line, and the result is printed below.

The reason you didn't see any results when evaluating the assignments to `x` and `y` is because nothing is returned, by default.

By way of explanation as to why the Python/IPython REPLs work this way, while the R one doesn't, is because SublimeREPL is very modular, and for the most part is just a thin wrapper surrounding native code. Therefore, the exact mechanism of transferring and displaying data may differ from Python to Ruby to R to Clojure, for example, and you may see slightly different behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted something more interactive. I wanted both the `In[#]` with text followed by an `Out[#]` with the output. I also did not want to switch from my source code to REPL just to get a damn `Out[#]`.

Like this, for example...
[image]
The solution I came up with is a lot more complicated than the post above but you get that interactive feel that one gets when using R with Sublime Text. You can find my solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27562036/3987905

Be sure to keep `"show_transferred_text": false`. Enabling it appears to mess up the plug-in. Hope it helps.